# Integrating application shopping cart with PayPal through PayPal API

Tags: angularjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need to integrate PayPal with my client AngularJS app, where the app visitors can donate specific amounts of money based on various causes, but not sure where to start? My client requested that visitors can select cause, amount to be donated, then get routed to Paypal to enter their details, process payment then finally routed back to the app for (thank you page) which should receive payment confirmation as parameter.

I've skimmed through the PayPal developers API and can see that there are a lot of options / features offered but not sure really where to start and which is the best approach to accomplish my client needs? Shall I use REST API? or will simple button integration do the job? What if I need to add causes selected to Paypal checkout page? Can I do this using the API? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have some specific reason to use REST I would recommend just going with the Classic API, specifically [Express Checkout](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/overview-ec.pdf).  It's much more mature and provides a lot more freedom to integrate with different options and customization.

With Express Checkout you'll be using the following calls.

- [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)
- [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/)

You'll call SEC and that will return a token.  Then you'll redirect the user to PayPal with that token appended to the URL.  The user signs in and approves the payment, and they're returned to a URL that you supply in the SEC request.

At that URL you can call GECD to obtain all the details about the buyer.  This allows you to tae their address and apply any shipping or tax rules you need to so that you can present a final review before the user would approve the payment, which is when you trigger DECP to finalize the transaction.

There are various options with that flow.  For example, GECD is optional, and depending on your flow you may or may not need a final review, so you could skip straight to DECP and display nothing but a final receipt page when the user gets back to your site if you want to.

If you happen to be using PHP my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/) will make all of this very simple for you.